# mod_rewrite both works and does not

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im creating a website and something weird is going on since I deployed it on my web server.

I have a very basic mod_rewrite file which I'm using for other websites without an issue.

What my intent is, www.example.com/a/b/c... rewrites to www.example.com/index.php?url=a/b/c..
and I use php to explode the $_GET["url"] and take the variables.

the contents of my .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and there is nothing else in it.

**The Problem:**
Although this .htaccess file is working on my other sites ( www.baymasal.com ) for example.
This site redirects as soon as I load it:

www.example.com redirects to www.example.com/index.php?url=index.shtml

the site is working as intended except my variables are visible.

when I click a link like example.com/en - goes to -> example.com/index.php?url=en 
when I click on a link like example.com/en/article -> works as intended. No variables are visible.

**Additional Info**
I work on my local machine using wamp, and everything works perfectly. 
The server thats causing trouble is my fatcow.com host.

Comment: Servers handle .htaccess differently, I would contact them.

Comment: I probably will do that, but they respond in at least 24 hours so I thought I'd try this great place for the first time :). I also wanted to make sure that the problem is not my mod_rewrite file or something I did :/

Comment: Check there is absolutely no other .htaccess file, even on parent directories.

Comment: I have 4 folders at the same level like site1, site2, site3. There is no .htaccess file in the root folder but there is one .htaccess file in each of these folders as they are different websites with domains pointed at them as root